# Cannot connect to remote vmware workstation

Tags: vmware-workstation

Hello I have shared VM on my home wokstation. I want to use that VM-s from my work. So I decided to use vmware workstation connect to remote server function. I entered my ip, my windows user name and password and it successfully connects and shows my virtuals. So I started one of my virtuals and it replied Unable to connect to the MKS: Login (username/password) incorrect. I have open 443 port on my router. What can I do else?

Answer (score 1):

I has similar problem today - the client console was trying to connect to port 903, but authd was listening to 902 and 912. 
The solution was:

1. On the "Server" VMWorkstation open "C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation\config.ini"
2. change authd.client.port to "902" i.e.:

   authd.client.port = "902"

That worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

MKS needs a prober DNS resolution. So when you open your router (perhaps you also use NAT), this will not work. Try to setting your hosts file for proper resolution.
DNS is used here by design from Vmware. Perhaps it helps if you add the following entry in hosts file:
 vmhost vmhost.local.domain

Also be aware, I might remember that you need port tcp/902 open as well.

ciao
ryder

Comment: But I use IP to connect to my home. Why dns is a problem? and what I must write in host accross of my IP? )))